# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of '_Printer' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x

## Trying to program a vending machine

I'm trying to check if the entered money is enough. (`products`)
But it keeps giving me that error-message. (`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of '_Printer' and 'int'`)

```
products = {

    "A": [100, "cola"],
    "B": [100, "drink0"]

}


def coinCounter():
    print("Bitte Münzen einwerfen! / Betrag eingeben!")

    credits = int(input("Betrag: "))


def product():
    print("Bitte Produkt wählen!")

    choosedProduct = input("Produkt: ").capitalize()

    if choosedProduct in products and credits >= products[choosedProduct][0]:
        output = True
    elif choosedProduct not in products:
        print("Das Produkt existiernt nicht.")
    elif products[choosedProduct][0] >= credits:
        print("Du hast nicht genug Geld eingeworfen")

    def moneyBack(moneyBack):
        moneyBack = credits - products[choosedProduct][0]
        print("Zurück: ", moneyBack)


    def output(output, choosedProduct):
        if output == True:
            print("Das Produkt", choosedProduct[1], "wird ausgegeben...")
            output = False

    output()
    moneyBack()



def main():
    coinCounter()
    product()

main()
```

Comment: Hint : `credits >= products[choosedProduct][0]`, you see anything wrong there ?

Comment: Also, where is the `coin` function? I think that's supposed to be `coinCounter()`

Comment: try `credits = int(input("Betrag: "))`, because `input()` returns a string.

Comment: @scharette I also tried it like this: `if choosedProduct in products and credits >= products(choosedProduct[0]):
        output = True` but then it says: `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: Check the line that @scharette mentioned, there's a mathematical error there. Your second hit is `choosedProduct = input("Produkt: ").capitalize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is one of scope.

When you set `credits` in `coinCounter`, this assignment is local to the function and not visible to the outside world. Why does your script not crash with a `NameError`? Because there is a global builtin object called `credits`, which you can call (or print) to see a short copyright notice:

```
>>> credits
    Thanks to CWI, CNRI, BeOpen.com, Zope Corporation and a cast of thousands
    for supporting Python development.  See www.python.org for more information.
```

You try to compare this object to an integer, which fails.

Instead, have `coinCounter` return the amount of credits and call `coinCounter` either in `product`, or call it in `main` and give the value as an argument to `product`:

```
products = {

    "A": [100, "cola"],
    "B": [100, "drink0"]

}


def coinCounter():
    print("Bitte Münzen einwerfen! / Betrag eingeben!")

    return int(input("Betrag: "))


def product(credits):
    print("Bitte Produkt wählen!")

    choosedProduct = input("Produkt: ").capitalize()

    if choosedProduct in products and credits >= products[choosedProduct][0]:
        output = True
    elif choosedProduct not in products:
        print("Das Produkt existiernt nicht.")
    elif products[choosedProduct][0] >= credits:
        print("Du hast nicht genug Geld eingeworfen")

    def moneyBack(moneyBack):
        moneyBack = credits - products[choosedProduct][0]
        print("Zurück: ", moneyBack)


    def output(output, choosedProduct):
        if output == True:
            print("Das Produkt", choosedProduct[1], "wird ausgegeben...")
            output = False

    output()
    moneyBack()



def main():
    credits = coinCounter()
    product(credits)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#input

"`TypeError` exception is raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch": https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError

You cannot compare a `string` to an `int`, therefore you have to convert the input value to `int`: `int(input("Betrag: "))`.

`

Comment: I did! `credits = int(input("Betrag: "))` but it gives me the same error. `File "Documents/python/vendingMachine.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "Documents/python/vendingMachine.py", line 49, in main
    product()
  File "Documents/python/vendingMachine.py", line 25, in product
    if choosedProduct in products and credits >= products[choosedProduct[0]]:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of '_Printer' and 'list'`

Comment: I see that you changed your code a little. As @scharatte pointed, there is a problem on line 25. Try to debug more, and find out what are the values for the objects that you are comparing, before the program gets at line 25.